# Microsoft Bot Framework testing connection now only results in internal service errors

Tags: azure, internal-server-error, botframework

Whenever I test my bot using the "test connection to your bot" feature, it only response with "internal service error" and a 500 status code. It didn't do this yesterday, and I havent changed anything since then.
What more, the bot works fine when I run it on the bot framework emulator on my local machine.

Whats more, whenever I try to access the logs for my bot in azure, I get an error code saying that my app isn't running, even though according to the azure portal it is.

What's causing this?
Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any way you can share the bot with us (or rather botId) so we can look in the logs?

have you tried talking to your bot in the cloud using the emulator?  You can change that localhost endpoint to point to your cloud service and try from there.

Comment: I just tried changing the endpoint on the emulator to the bots endpoint, and it works when I do that.
I don't know if there is a way to share the logs, other than taking a screenshot

Comment: The bot id is gaikbot, if that helps at all

Comment: If you send us a mail at bf-reports@Microsoft.com let me follow up with you privately and send you a trace of what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem to this. But changing the endpoint did nothing. Linked to the solution we came upon here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36789806/1152015