# What's causing 500 Internal Server Error due to localhost:9000 being hit in bot framework?

Tags: botframework

Getting this error every time I try to send a message to my bot, or after it responds with 3 messages in a row.

I put a `try/catch` around the code that's getting the exception (from a call to `context.PostAsync`) and got this logged in my Application Insights instance:

```
An error occurred while sending the request.
Unable to connect to the remote server
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Certainly nothing in *my* code is hitting `localhost`... anybody else seeing this?

Code that's running when the error occurs:

```
var j = JToken.Parse(responseJson);
foreach (var b in j["value"])
{
    await context.PostAsync($"{b.Value<string>("id")} - {b.Value<string>("name")}");
}
```

When I run the bot locally and use the Emulator to test I get 3 items output but 500 on the 4th (which isn't malformed in a way such that the json resolution is failing).

When I publish out to Azure App Services, I get 500 error without any output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were having a similar issue in our app. Managed to resolve the 500 Invalid responses by not having a private `LuisResult` property in our dialog class that derived from `LuisDialog`.

I guess as the class was marked as `Serializable` it tried to serialize all the properties and a `LuisResult` can't be serialized.

Here's a code snippet:

Change:

```
[Serializable]
public class YourDialog : LuisDialog<MySerializableClass>
{
    private LuisResult _myPrivateProp;
}
```

To:

```
[Serializable]
public class YourDialog : LuisDialog<MySerializableClass>
{
    private string _myPrivateProp;//or whatever
}
```

Comment: I think the root of our problem was indeed `Serializable` - however it was quite weird the bot would respond just fine for the first few queries when it **didn't** have the attribute...... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Did you connect to your deployed service via the emulator?

If so that could generate this error, because when we see a message from channelId="emulator" async messages are routed to http://localhost:9000.  That would cause this port to be used.

To test it deployed you should start with the Test window on the bot configuration page, or use the web chat control.

Comment: interesting... so what do I have to do if I've connected via emulator? re-deploy the bot to azure and make sure not to touch it w/ emulator first?
Also does this explain the 3-then-500 behavior as well?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the  “500 internal server error” 
updating to the latest "Bot Framework Emulator" solved my issue.

[Link to Bot Framework Emulator](https://emulator.botframework.com/) :

[Documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-emulator/wiki/Getting-Started):

Hope this helps.