# How to reset credentials in console version of the Bot Framework Channel Emulator v3?

Tags: botframework

There is an issue in v3.0.0 of the botbuilder / bot framework where authentication does not work with the local emulator (see https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/625). The official workaround is to clear the appId and appPassword from the bot itself and from the emulator, thus bypassing authentication altogether.

This is easy in the Windows GUI version of the emulator, but in the console version this does not work. /settings allows you to change appId and appPassword, however pressing  without any input will leave the current values. Hence you can't set them to nothing.

I tried adding a blank, commands like /reset, but nothing worked. Deleting / reinstalling the console emulator did keep the values, so they seem to me cached somewhere.

**Is there a way to clear the settings cache / reset the credentials for the console emulator?**

Using: Mono, Console version of Microsoft Bot Framework Channel Emulator v3, Mac OS

Comment: Info: Deleting the directory, rebooting the machine and a re-install in a different directory solved the issue: It reset the settings and appId and appPassword are empty.Since this is a bit tedious the question still stands if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just created a new version (v3.0.6037.27277) which fixes this (you can type 'disable' to disable AppId/AppPassword.)
It has been published.

Thanks
-Tom

Comment: Thanks! Super appreciated!