# Error while using Bot Framework Emulator after publishing a bot V3 on Azure

Tags: .net, azure, bots, botframework

I created a quite simple bot, using the version 1.1.0 of Bot Builder, and it worked fine, both locally and after publishing on Azure. However, when I changed to the version 3 (and changed the respective code), my bot is working locally, but it is not working (on Bot emulator) after I have published it on azure. I don't know if I am using the Emulator in a wrong way, or if I am publishing it wrongly.

I changed the BotId, MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword tags of the webconfig.

When I use the button "Test connection to your bot" on Azure page, it responds "Accepted".

On the emulator, I am using the Bot Url as "https://XXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/api/messages", the Emulator URL as "http://localhost:9000/" and the respective AppId and AppPassword.
The version of the emulator is 3.0.0.59

When I try to iniciate a conversation, I receive the 500 InternalError {"An error has occurred"}

Any ideias of what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve the error as “500 internal server error” in Bot Framework Channel Emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306884/how-to-resolve-the-error-as-500-internal-server-error-in-bot-framework-channel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages are being routed to the Emulator URL http://localhost:9000 that's why this is not working. 
You need to forward the messages to a known location out on the web when trying to interact with your bot in the cloud using the emulator. For that purpose, you can use ngrok.

This [topic](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/tools/bot-framework-emulator/#using-the-emulator-with-ngrok-to-interact-with-your-bot-in-the-cloud) in the documentation explain how to do it. Basically you need to run ngrok in this way:

> ngrok http -host-header=rewrite 9000

And then update the emulator to use the https ngrok forwarding URL in the Emulator URL textbox.